# Separate objects in an array from their index using localstorage

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to separate objects from an array, having only the index avaiable. I have something like this:

```
     var hello= [];
     for (var i=0; incr.lenght>0; i++;)
     {

        hello+= originalarray[incr[i]].item;

       }
```

**Array:**
0: item0
1: item1
2: item2
3: item3

**Having this:** hello+= originalarray[incr[0,2,3]].item;

**I get this**: item0item2item3

The "item" comes from another array, this is a small part of my code, but hopefully it's enough to explain my problem.
When I create an alert(hello); what I get is a list of item like this: item0item1item2item3. What I am looking for is a way to separate them. But I need to use the localStorage as well, and I was thinking of creating a different key for every value of the index. Hope it makes sense, I am a new user. Thank you very much!

Comment: Using `+=` is not how you insert into an array. You are turning everything into a string. Suggest studying some array fundamentals tutorials

Comment: `push` `push` `push`.

Comment: @charlietfl what should I be using?

Comment: @trincot I was thinking of using push, but I haven't figure out yet how to use it with localstorage

Comment: A quick web search for "javascript insert array" would answer that question very quickly

Comment: You can also store whole arrays in localstorage. Unfortunately Stackoverflow isn't really a *"how to"* tutorial service and most of what you are trying to do is fairly easy to research

Comment: You need to dig into a fundamentals tutorial. No offense man, just trying to help you level up quickly.

Comment: @BenSteward I will! thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `for` loop you have in your question has several issues:

- It has three `;`, while the syntax only allows two. You need to remove the final one
- It has a condition that is never true, because `lenght` has a spelling mistake. If you correct it it will always be true (infinite loop):

  ```
  incr.length>0
  ```

  This should be:

  ```
  i < incr.length
  ```

Then the main issue is that you apply a string operator (`+=`) to concatenate the items, and so `hello` is no longer an array, but a string:

```
    hello+= originalarray[incr[i]].item;
```

Instead you should use `push`:

```
    hello.push(originalarray[incr[i]].item);
```

In order to store `hello` in localStorage you should not try to make a key for each item and store each separately. Instead use `JSON.stringify` (for writing) and `JSON.parse` (for reading) as explained in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/5459839).

Comment: Please read again, I wrote it in a negative way: *"It has a condition that is never true"*. Also note I wrote *"If you correct it"* to make the other claim.